# How to repeat PDF content in one page mirrored

Tags: pdf, merge, pdf-generation, acrobat

I would like to multiplicate a pdf page 4 times and produce one single (larger) page that contains that 4 mini page. There is an Acrobat plugin called AutoPagex which can repeat page content and produce an other page with them, but I need in that way that the 2 page bellow should be upside down (see the image). Can somebody help me? Which application can do that?

It will be also good if I could merge two pages into one...

[image: Mirrored content duplication]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with

**Multivalent**

- https://rg.to/file/c6bd7f31bf8885bcaa69b50ffab7e355/Multivalent20060102.jar.html
  (latest free version with tools included, current has no tools in itself)

you can do the trick

```
java -cp path....to/Multivalent.jar tool.pdf.Impose -dim 2x2 -paper 2widhtx2heightin -layout 1,1,1u,1u file.pdf
```

- http://ifile.it/v19xd0j/singlepagerepeatedmirrored.pdf

[image: single pdf page repeated and 2 times mirrored]

**explanations:**

if your copy of Multivalent.jar resides  in **/mnt/home/** then your path will be ***java -cp /mnt/home/Multivalent.jar***

> **-paper** parameter indicates the *width* and *height* of page containing 4 times your original pdf page, so, its dimensions, need to be
> calculated doubling width and height of your original page size

> **in** = inches [other allowed units are **pt** (points) or **cm** (centimeters)]

notes: this work flow is intended to be working if you have a single source pdf page.
If you have a multipage source pdf, then the way to do this trick is different; please, give to us further details in this case

e.g.

for **multipage** source pdf whose you need to repeat **every page 4 times ** (* 2 times rotated by 180 degrees*) **one same PAGE**, ...use this script that relies on **pdfinfo** and **Multivalent.jar**:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# a dingo's script to repeat one same page 4 times in another page (once rotated by 0 degrees, and  twice, at bottom, rotated by 180 degrees)
# usage (it asks for 3 arguments):
#
# nameofscript file.pdf number of pages Multivalent.jar path
#
#example: rotatepdfpage4times file.pdf 16 /mnt/home
#
pdfname=$1
pages=$2
multivalentpath=$3
xfactor=x
ptunit=pt
u="u"
rep="$(for ((a=1, b=1; a <= $pages; a++, b++)); do echo -n "$a $b $a$u $b$u "; done |xargs | tr ' ' ',')"
origsizewidth="$(pdfinfo -box 1.pdf| grep MediaBox | cut -d : -f2 | awk '{print x  $3 FS $4}' | tr ' ' 'x' | cut -d x -f1 | cut -d . -f1)"
origsizeheight="$(pdfinfo -box 1.pdf| grep MediaBox | cut -d : -f2 | awk '{print x  $3 FS $4}' | tr ' ' 'x' | cut -d x -f2 | cut -d . -f1)"
doublewidth="`let MULTIPLICATION=$origsizewidth*2; echo $MULTIPLICATION`"
doubleheight="`let MULTIPLICATION=$origsizeheight*2; echo $MULTIPLICATION`"
echo $pdfname
echo $pages
echo $rep
echo $doublewidth
echo $doubleheight
echo "$doublewidth$xfactor$doubleheight$ptunit"
java -cp $multivalentpath/Multivalent.jar tool.pdf.Impose  -dim 2x2 -paper "$doublewidth$xfactor"$doubleheight$ptunit -layout "$rep" "$pdfname"
exit 0
```

http://ifile.it/m7tr4g0 (sample source pdf file - A5 size - 595x841 pt)

http://ifile.it/rscpoxi (same source pdf imposed 4 times -paper 1190x1682pt, in one page)

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable with [pdfjam](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam/) or [podofoimpose](http://podofo.sourceforge.net/tools.html).